# Featured images not showing on my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, wpbakery

I have a WordPress site when I disable wpbakery plugin it shows featured images on posts but when I activate it doesn't show. My plugin is latest version

Comment: in cutom post type or post? and  not showing on admin panel or frontend?

Comment: http://www.custompagetemplates.com/add-featured-image-visual-composer-content/
Please give more information, visual composer have different code it's work based on your content.

Comment: Are you using any premium themes? If yes please check single.php page for the structure. It would be good if you can share the URL.

Answer (score 0):

After Post title add this code.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

Check Code for more [details](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/)